# How does Google App Engine scales down and what I should prepare for it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using Java on Google App Engine, and many libraries (including the client library of Google Cloud Pubsub) requires "graceful shutdown" when the Java process is terminated.

This is usually done by implementing some custom finalizer, but I'm uncertain how each instance is terminated in Google App Engine (i.e. whether SIGKILL or SIGTERM, or even shutdown of virtual instance).

How do I realize a "graceful shutdown" with Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not said whether you are using Standard or Flexible, and whether you are using Automatic, Basic, or Manual scaling.  But I think you'll find your answer at:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed

If you need certain cleanup to occur before an instance shuts down, you may need to handle the `/_ah/stop` url that GAE will send.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! It was the exact answer I wanted! I use the standard environment, and I will note it at the next time.